# How to access adjacent props in event handlers within single component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This should be fairly clear, but I cannot find the answer.

I just want to pass the value set on another prop to the `onClick` handler that is in the same component props.

```
<Button
  ariaLabel="Click to Open"
  onClick={() => this.chooseAlertToggle([I WANT THE children PROP])}
  children="Info/Default"
  color="primary"
/>
```

Because the `children` prop is user defined and I need that value to control a toggle. I don't know the proper way to access it. I need the effect to be 
`onClick={() => this.chooseAlertToggle("Info/Default)}`, not the string literally, but the reference to the `children` prop

I have tried some guesses at syntax like `this.children` that I know are incorrect, just shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
<Button
  ariaLabel="Click to Open"
  onClick={() => this.chooseAlertToggle(this.props.children)}
  children="Info/Default"
  color="primary"
/>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: That was one of my attempts, but it returns `undefined` since that instead refers to the props that are passed to the parent component that `<Button />` lives inside.

Comment: I guess I am confused as to what you are trying to do then.  You want access to the children props of the button component?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the value that you pass to the children prop to the chooseAlertToggle callback.

```
<Button
 ariaLabel="Click to Open"
 onClick={this.chooseAlertToggle.bind(this, "Info/Default")}
 children="Info/Default"
 color="primary"
```

/>

Comment: Hmm, but would that enable a reusable block? The content of `children` will change, but I'd like the passed property to simply refer to the prop name like it were a variable and not need to repeat the same string content within the onClick argument.

Comment: Since the value for children; in this case "Info/Default" is passed by the component rendering <Button/> component, the value should be present in the component in a variable.